# How to fix broken chromium browser in 22.04 (snap)

Tags: 22.04, snap, chromium, wayland

This morning I used Chromium without any problems. This afternoon it won't start up. I tried the usual walking away to make a cup of tea while a snap thinks about starting up trick, but nope, it never appeared.

Runnning `chromium-browser` from the command line gave:

```
WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation not permitted
[0118/155937.850543:ERROR:ptracer.cc(567)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0118/155937.850638:ERROR:ptracer.cc(567)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0118/155937.869643:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  chromium
```

Although now (after logging out and in again) it gives:

```
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: symbol lookup error: ln: undefined symbol: , version GLIBC_2.2.5
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: symbol lookup error: ln: undefined symbol: , version GLIBC_2.2.5
/snap/chromium/2271/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verdef record
/snap/chromium/2271/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

The snap-store app also crashes:

```
ln: symbol lookup error: ln: undefined symbol: , version GLIBC_2.2.5
/snap/snap-store/638/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/638/gnome-platform/usr/lib/libwayland-cursor.so.0: undefined symbol: wl_buffer_interface
```

I did a `snap refresh` and it tells me they're all up-to date. I did `snap list` and they all have green ticks (except one which has a ✪ symbol).

I did a `snap remove chromium; snap install chromium` and now it gives more errors

```
ln: ln: no version information available (required by ln)
ln: symbol lookup error: ln: undefined symbol: , version GLIBC_2.2.5
/snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verdef record
/snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: error while loading shared libraries: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
ERROR: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
/snap/chromium/2271/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verdef record
/snap/chromium/2271/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: /snap/chromium/2271/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

My system is up-to-date on  Ubuntu 22.04, running Wayland (I mention as it's mentioned in the logs, and well, it often breaks). I have not updated my kernel or anything between it working this morning and failing now.

I'm keen to get Chromium working again as it's the only browser that works to do screensharing over WebRTC sites properly on Wayland.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot seems to have fixed it.

Apparently (See comment from @user535733) the error message suggest something in the kernel crashed, so the only fix is a reboot.

Comment: Your output shows that the issue was far more than "*just an app that crashed*." A reboot was appropriate.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clarifying. Thing is if you ask why snaps crashed my kernel (which used to be pretty hard to achieve) they down vote you as a Luddite. Snaps are the way. Snaps are the future. Let nobody say I think otherwise. 

Comment: Many questions that ask "*why did ABC cause XYZ?*" get downvoted for good reasons. Assuming that ABC is the problem without troubleshooting evidence...or when that evidence points to a completely different cause...are good, valid reasons for downvoting. The querant can edit the question to something more like "*what caused XYZ so I can file a bug report?*" which is much less likely to be downvoted.